# automapping Entities in nhibernate

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

hii i am having a little problem in mapping all the entities in contained in the namespace "nhibernateTest.Domain" . it basically contains all the Map Classes like , StudentMap, DepartmentMap etc. .. now in case of normal nhibernate what we used to do is :

```
 private ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;
    private Configuration _configuration;

    [TestFixtureSetUp]
    public void TestFixtureSetUp()
    {

        _configuration = new Configuration().Configure().AddAssembly("nHibernateTest");      
        _sessionFactory = _configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
    }
```

now what it used to do is . look for all the "*.hbm.xml" files in my namespace and automatically map them...

can someone tell me how to do the same for fluent nHibernate ? so that it looks for all map classes and automatically map them so that i dont have to create the session separately for diffrent Map classes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to specify your mappings when configuring Fluent NHibernate in your application. This is typically done by

```
Fluently.Configure()
  .Database(/* your database settings */)
  .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<StudentMap>())
  .ExposeConfiguration(/* alter Configuration */) // optional
  .BuildSessionFactory();
```

The code above is from this excellent [link](http://jagregory.com/writings/fluent-nhibernate-configuring-your-application/) which talks about how to configure Fluent.

Comment: @worldlsRound can you please tell  AddFromAssemblyOf<StudentMap> does that take all the map classes from loaded in the assembly nhibernateTest.Domain ??? i need a little bit of clearance on the method how does it work .. can you please explain it to me ?

Comment: What application are you building? Is it a windows app or a web forms? Fluent is configured typically at application start up.

Comment: @Joy: To answer to your first question, yes. It would pick up all map classes from the assembly nhibernateTest.Domain. If you read the link I posed above it perfectly explains on what each method does. You can also refer the Fluent wiki - http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Fluent_configuration

Comment: @ worldlsRound   i am building basically for web application :)